# i don't know why is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i'm making coinnew use redux i have some problem why it's not a function??

```
  import HTMLReactParser from "html-react-parser";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import millify from "millify";
import { Col, Row, Typography, Select } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";

import { useGetCryptoDetailsQuery } from "../services/coinDetailApi";

const { Title, Text } = Typography;
const { Option } = Select;

const CryptoDetails = () => {
  const { coinId } = useParams();
  console.log(coinId);
  const [timePeriod, setTimePeriod] = useState("7d");
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptoDetailsQuery(coinId);
  const cryptoDetails = data?.data?.coin;

  return <div>CryptoDetails </div>;
};

export default CryptoDetails;
```

program say useGetCryptoDetailsQuery is not a function
i don't know help me!!

it is my Api code

```
const baseUrl = "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com";

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });
export const cryptoDetailsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "cryptoApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptoDetails: builder.query({
      query: (coinId) => createRequest(`/coin/${coinId}`)
    })
  })
});

export const { usegetCryptoDetails } = cryptoDetailsApi;
```

this is my redux code

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { cryptoApi } from "../services/coinApi";
import { cryptoDetailsApi } from "../services/coinDetailApi";
import { cryptoNewsApi } from "../services/coinNewsApi";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
    [cryptoNewsApi.reducerPath]: cryptoNewsApi.reducer,
    [cryptoDetailsApi.reducerPath]: cryptoDetailsApi.reducer
  }
});
```

plz help me!! ㅜㅡㅜ

Comment: Where have you defined `useGetCryptoDetailsQuery` ?

Comment: import { useGetCryptoDetailsQuery } from "../services/coinDetailApi";
here!!

Comment: i update my code plz help me! @Kundan

Comment: You're exporting `usegetCryptoDetails` but importing `useGetCryptoDetailsQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You export the wrong hook function. There is a little typo. You didn't capitalize "g" letter in "usegetCryptoDetails":

`export const { usegetCryptoDetails } = cryptoDetailsApi;`

should be:

`export const { useGetCryptoDetails } = cryptoDetailsApi;`